# ups shutdown signal --> shutdown other computers

Tags: windows-server-2008, shutdown

Our UPS will send shutdown signal to the computer on the serial port when the UPS power is about to drop.

Can this computer be configured to shut down any other computers before itself upon this signal?

Comment: This might help: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292725/Using-WM-POWER-events-to-monitor-a-UPS

Answer (score 0):

you would need additional logic on that or a third party application maybe. basically my idea is to use [Powershell](http://www.wekabyte.co.uk/2009/01/remote-shutdown-with-powershell/) to shutdown other computer remotely. i would create a program to listen if the computer is shutting down and it will call the powershell script to shutdown remote computer. hope it helps.